# Running Virtual box and Ubuntu 17.04 on a Razer Blade Stealth - time outs

Tags: virtualbox, 17.04

I have a Razer Bladed Stealth Laptop, and I have intalled Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 on it.

I have also installed the latest version of Virtualbox.

All works well and I can run

> vagrant up

and

> vagrant ssh

and I can see my files are mirrored inside the box. Thing is when I go to the URL in the browser and expect it to load the site it times out every time.

I have another laptop next to me running ubuntu 14.04 and I have cross checked all the config files and it should be working.

Variables are:
Ubuntu 14.04 (working) vs Ubuntu 17.04 (not working)
The hardware the newer Razer Blade Stealth is not working

Trying to solve this, I have found some references to [issues with Virtualization](https://gorka.eguileor.com/vbox-vmware-in-secureboot-linux-2016-update/), and I have turned of "Safe boot".

The linked article also says:

> This post also applies if you are running your system with module
>   signature verification enabled (CONFIG_MODULE_SIG) even if it’s not
>   running in Secure Boot.

I can't seem to tell if this is turned on or not for a normal install of Ubuntu Gnome 17.04? If so, I need to recompile the linux kernal in order to turn this off?

Otherwise I'm stumped. My hosts file is the same as on the working laptop, and the box seems to be up since I can ssh into it. The files are there...

...but some how it's not getting from the browser to load the virtual website.

I'm stuck.

Please let me know how I can debug this :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with all vagrant boxes and found the solution to be:

removing the second line in the /etc/hosts file
just uncomment or remove the line containing:

```
 127.0.1.1 [computer-name]
```

Installing net-tools:
It seems like ubuntu 17.04 is not installing the package net-tools anymore.

So installing them via

```
 sudo apt-get install net-tools
```

and it should work again.